# numpy ndarray generic indexing - is there a better way?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to use a tuple indexing of numpy ndarray but it is immutable. So, I use a list and convert it to a tuple. Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np 

# uncomment one of the following: 
# dim = 0 
dim = 1 

m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
loc = [0, 0]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        loc[dim] = i 
        loc[1-dim] = j
        print(m[tuple(loc)], end='') 
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `array.item()` function, you can expand the indices from a list:

```
import numpy as np

# uncomment one of the following: 
# dim = 0 
dim = 1

m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
loc = [0, 0]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        loc[dim] = i
        loc[1-dim] = j
        print(m.item(*loc), end='')
    print()
```